# SQL Only Include Working Hours in AVG Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'v had a look through the forum but couldn't find anything specific enough for my scenario so here goes.

I have the following query which calculates the average time for a group of entries across multiple tables in a defined date period. The 3 types (IR, SR, CR) all are linked to a table (WorkItems). The Query I have for the average time is below. (the parameters are used in reporting services and a date picker)

```
Select 
WIAvgAssign = AVG(
Case When WI.id Like 'IR%' Then DATEDIFF(hour,wi.CreatedDate,IR.FirstAssignedDate)
When WI.Id Like 'SR%' Then DATEDIFF(hour,wi.CreatedDate,SR.FirstAssignedDate)
When WI.Id Like 'SR%' Then DATEDIFF(hour,wi.CreatedDate,CR.FirstAssignedDate)
END),
IRAvgAssign = AVG(DATEDIFF(hour,wi.CreatedDate,IR.FirstAssignedDate)),
SRAvgAssign = AVG(DATEDIFF(hour,wi.CreatedDate,SR.FirstAssignedDate)),
CRAvgAssign = AVG(DATEDIFF(hour,wi.CreatedDate,CR.FirstAssignedDate))
from WorkItemDimvw WI
Left Outer Join IncidentDimvw IR on WI.EntityDimKey=IR.EntityDimKey
Left Outer Join ServiceRequestDimvw SR on WI.EntityDimKey=SR.EntityDimKey
Left Outer Join ChangeRequestDimvw CR on WI.EntityDimKey=CR.EntityDimKey
Where (IR.ResolvedDate >= @StartDate AND IR.ResolvedDate < @EndDate) OR
(SR.CompletedDate >= @StartDate AND SR.CompletedDate < @EndDate) OR
(CR.ActualEndDate >=@StartDate AND CR.ActualEndDate < @EndDate)
```

I have a table which contains each day of the week and the hours of operation for that particular day (the date is when the entry was created, it's just the time I'm interested in), the values for the weekend are blank.

```
Day          Start Time                  End Time
Monday       2014-03-06 09:00:00.000     2014-03-06 17:00:00.000
Tuesday      2014-03-06 09:00:00.000     2014-03-06 17:00:00.000
Wednesday    2014-03-06 09:00:00.000     2014-03-06 17:00:00.000
Thursday     2014-03-06 09:00:00.000     2014-03-06 17:00:00.000
Friday       2014-03-06 09:00:00.000     2014-03-06 17:00:00.000
Saturday     NULL                        NULL
Sunday       NULL                        NULL
```

The average results in hours that I get currently are not specific to the hours of operation so I would like to be able to strip out when the office is closed and provide a more accurate average.

Thanks

Edit - I've come up with this, it's a bit inefficient as I've specified the number of non-working hours manually in the query and added in a calculation for weekends. Looking at the individual records I think it's correct. I've taken out the CR calculation for the time being

```
Declare @StartDate datetime
Declare @EndDate datetime
Set @StartDate = '2015/01/01'
Set @EndDate = '2015/12/31'
Select
AVG(
CASE WHEN CAST(wi.createddate as date) = 
CAST(
CASE
WHEN WI.Id like 'IR%' then CASE WHEN ir.FirstAssignedDate !=NULL THEN ir.firstassigneddate else GETDATE() END
WHEN WI.Id like 'SR%' then CASE WHEN sr.firstassigneddate !=NULL THEN Sr.firstassigneddate else GETDATE() END
END
as date)
THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR,wi.CreatedDate,
CASE
WHEN WI.Id like 'IR%' then CASE WHEN ir.FirstAssignedDate !=NULL THEN ir.firstassigneddate else GETDATE() END
WHEN WI.Id like 'SR%' then CASE WHEN sr.firstassigneddate !=NULL THEN Sr.firstassigneddate else GETDATE() END
END)
ELSE (DATEDIFF(hour,wi.CreatedDate,DATEADD(hour,-15*DATEDIFF(day,wi.CreatedDate,CASE
WHEN WI.Id like 'IR%' then CASE WHEN ir.FirstAssignedDate !=NULL THEN ir.firstassigneddate else GETDATE() END
WHEN WI.Id like 'SR%' then CASE WHEN sr.firstassigneddate !=NULL THEN Sr.firstassigneddate else GETDATE() END
END),CASE
WHEN WI.Id like 'IR%' then CASE WHEN ir.FirstAssignedDate !=NULL THEN ir.firstassigneddate else GETDATE() END
WHEN WI.Id like 'SR%' then CASE WHEN sr.firstassigneddate !=NULL THEN Sr.firstassigneddate else GETDATE() END
END)))-48*DATEDIFF(wk,wi.CreatedDate,CASE
WHEN WI.Id like 'IR%' then CASE WHEN ir.FirstAssignedDate !=NULL THEN ir.firstassigneddate else GETDATE() END
WHEN WI.Id like 'SR%' then CASE WHEN sr.firstassigneddate !=NULL THEN Sr.firstassigneddate else GETDATE() END
END)
END)
from WorkItemDimvw WI
Left Outer Join IncidentDimvw IR on WI.EntityDimKey=IR.EntityDimKey
Left Outer Join ServiceRequestDimvw SR on WI.EntityDimKey=SR.EntityDimKey
Left Outer Join ChangeRequestDimvw CR on WI.EntityDimKey=CR.EntityDimKey
WHERE (wi.Id like 'IR%' or WI.ID like 'SR%') AND
((IR.ResolvedDate >=@StartDate AND IR.ResolvedDate < @EndDate) OR
(Sr.CompletedDate >=@StartDate AND SR.CompletedDate < @EndDate))
```

Comment: You're not doing left joins... Move those conditions from the `WHERE` clause to respectively `ON` clause to get true `LEFT JOIN` result. (As it is now you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: You should provide sample data and desire output. Beside Jarlh comment, First you need remove the date part otherwise wont match with different day, also  looks like you will average if overlap partially with operation time. You may be interested only on the hours perfomed on the right schedule.

Comment: The output needed is a single average value for all work items and for the IR, CR and SR individually, which is what it does now but I just need to exclude the non working hours from the calculated average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many more hours of tweaking I've come up with the following which I'm 90% sure is right. If there is any way of optimising the query that would be helpful.

```
Declare @StartDate datetime
Declare @EndDate datetime
Set @StartDate = '2016/01/01'
Set @EndDate = '2016/12/31'

SELECT  
   WIAvgAssign = AVG(
        Case 
            When id Like 'IR%' Then DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedIRAssignedDate)
            -(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedIRAssignedDate)*48)
            -((DATEDIFF(day,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedIRAssignedDate)-(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedIRAssignedDate)*2))*14)
            -(Case When DateName(dw,NormalizedCreatedDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END)
            -(Case When DATENAME(dw,NormalizedIRAssignedDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END)
            When id Like 'SR%' Then DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedSRAssignedDate)
            -(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedSRAssignedDate)*48)
            -((DATEDIFF(day,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedSRAssignedDate)-(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedSRAssignedDate)*2))*14)
            -(Case When DateName(dw,NormalizedCreatedDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END)
            -(Case When DATENAME(dw,NormalizedSRAssignedDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END)
            When id Like 'CR%' Then DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedCRAssignedDate)
            -(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedCRAssignedDate)*48)
            -((DATEDIFF(day,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedCRAssignedDate)-(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedCRAssignedDate)*2))*14)
            -(Case When DateName(dw,NormalizedCreatedDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END)
            -(Case When DATENAME(dw,NormalizedCRAssignedDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END)
        END),
    IRAvgAssign = AVG(DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedIRAssignedDate)
            -(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedIRAssignedDate)*48)
            -((DATEDIFF(day,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedIRAssignedDate)-(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedIRAssignedDate)*2))*14)
            -(Case When DateName(dw,NormalizedCreatedDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END)
            -(Case When DATENAME(dw,NormalizedIRAssignedDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END)),
    SRAvgAssign = AVG(DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedSRAssignedDate)
            -(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedSRAssignedDate)*48)
            -((DATEDIFF(day,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedSRAssignedDate)-(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedSRAssignedDate)*2))*14)
            -(Case When DateName(dw,NormalizedCreatedDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END)
            -(Case When DATENAME(dw,NormalizedSRAssignedDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END)),
    CRAvgAssign = AVG(DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedCRAssignedDate)
            -(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedCRAssignedDate)*48)
            -((DATEDIFF(day,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedCRAssignedDate)-(DATEDIFF(wk,normalizedcreateddate,NormalizedCRAssignedDate)*2))*14)
            -(Case When DateName(dw,NormalizedCreatedDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END)
            -(Case When DATENAME(dw,NormalizedCRAssignedDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 24 ELSE 0 END))
FROM (
        Select WI.id, 
            CASE 
                WHEN wi.CreatedDate < DATEADD(HOUR, 9, CAST(CAST(wi.CreatedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 9, CAST(CAST(wi.CreatedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                ELSE wi.CreatedDate
            END NormalizedCreatedDate,
            CASE
        WHEN IR.FirstAssignedDate !=NULL THEN CASE
                WHEN IR.FirstAssignedDate > DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(IR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(IR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                ELSE IR.FirstAssignedDate END 
        ELSE CASE WHEN IR.ResolvedDate > DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(IR.ResolvedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(IR.ResolvedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                ELSE IR.ResolvedDate END
            END NormalizedIRAssignedDate,
                        CASE
        WHEN SR.FirstAssignedDate !=NULL THEN CASE
                WHEN SR.FirstAssignedDate > DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(SR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(SR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                ELSE SR.FirstAssignedDate END 
        ELSE CASE WHEN SR.CompletedDate > DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(SR.CompletedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(SR.CompletedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                ELSE SR.CompletedDate END
            END NormalizedSRAssignedDate,
            CASE
        WHEN CR.FirstAssignedDate !=NULL THEN CASE
                WHEN CR.FirstAssignedDate > DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(CR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(CR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                ELSE CR.FirstAssignedDate END 
        ELSE CASE WHEN CR.ActualEndDate > DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(CR.ActualEndDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(CR.ActualEndDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                ELSE CR.ActualEndDate END
            END NormalizedCRAssignedDate
        from WorkItemDimvw WI
            Left Outer Join IncidentDimvw IR 
            on WI.EntityDimKey=IR.EntityDimKey
            Left Outer Join ServiceRequestDimvw SR 
            on WI.EntityDimKey=SR.EntityDimKey
            Left Outer Join ChangeRequestDimvw CR 
            on WI.EntityDimKey=CR.EntityDimKey
        Where (
                (IR.ResolvedDate >= @StartDate AND IR.ResolvedDate < @EndDate) 
                OR (SR.CompletedDate >= @StartDate AND SR.CompletedDate < @EndDate) 
                OR (CR.ActualEndDate >= @StartDate AND CR.ActualEndDate < @EndDate)
            )
    ) dataset
```

Edit - obviously we weren't excluding the time after 5pm (it's between 8 and 6 in my example as that's what my customer wanted) so I added in a calculation to remove 14 hours for every day (apart from weekends) the item is open which has given me what I believe to be the exact figures

Answer (score 0):

This has been an intriguing question for me. I assumed a few things in my approach to this one:

1. `CreatedDate` always happens before `FirstAssignedDate`
2. `SET DATEFIRST 7` (changes weekday numbers if different)
3. That is is okay to filter out `CreatedDate` and `FirstAssignedDate` if they are on a weekend

Here's my approach and I'm sure that it's wildly inefficient, but it was my first idea:

```
SELECT  
    WIAvgAssign = AVG(
        Case 
            When id Like 'IR%' Then DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedIRAssignedDate)
            When id Like 'SR%' Then DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedSRAssignedDate)
            When id Like 'SR%' Then DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedCRAssignedDate)
        END
    ),
    IRAvgAssign = AVG(DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedIRAssignedDate)),
    SRAvgAssign = AVG(DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedSRAssignedDate)),
    CRAvgAssign = AVG(DATEDIFF(hour,NormalizedCreatedDate,NormalizedCRAssignedDate))
FROM (
        Select WI.id, 
            CASE 
                WHEN wi.CreatedDate < DATEADD(HOUR, 9, CAST(CAST(wi.CreatedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 9, CAST(CAST(wi.CreatedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                ELSE wi.CreatedDate
            END NormalizedCreatedDate,
            CASE 
                WHEN IR.FirstAssignedDate > DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(IR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(IR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                ELSE IR.FirstAssignedDate
            END NormalizedIRAssignedDate,
            CASE 
                WHEN SR.FirstAssignedDate > DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(SR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(SR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                ELSE SR.FirstAssignedDate
            END NormalizedSRAssignedDate,
            CASE 
                WHEN CR.FirstAssignedDate > DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(CR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(CAST(CR.FirstAssignedDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                ELSE CR.FirstAssignedDate
            END NormalizedCRAssignedDate
        from WorkItemDimvw WI
            Left Outer Join IncidentDimvw IR 
            on WI.EntityDimKey=IR.EntityDimKey
            Left Outer Join ServiceRequestDimvw SR 
            on WI.EntityDimKey=SR.EntityDimKey
            Left Outer Join ChangeRequestDimvw CR 
            on WI.EntityDimKey=CR.EntityDimKey
            --AVOID SATURDAYS and SUNDAYS in result set
            --Also assumes SET DATEFIRST 7
        Where DATEPART(WEEKDAY,wi.CreatedDate) NOT IN (1,7) 
            AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,IR.FirstAssignedDate) NOT IN (1,7)
            AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,SR.FirstAssignedDate) NOT IN (1,7)
            AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CR.FirstAssignedDate) NOT IN (1,7)
            AND(
                (IR.ResolvedDate >= @StartDate AND IR.ResolvedDate < @EndDate) 
                OR (SR.CompletedDate >= @StartDate AND SR.CompletedDate < @EndDate) 
                OR (CR.ActualEndDate >= @StartDate AND CR.ActualEndDate < @EndDate)
            )
    ) dataset
```

So I basically just check if the `CreatedDate` < 0900 of the same day and set the time to 0900 if that is the case, and then I check if `FirstAssignedDate` > 1700 of the same day and set the time to 1700 if that is the case. I also filtered out all of the `CreatedDate`s and `FirstAssignedDate`s if they were on a weekend.

EDIT:

I updated the my original post. I changed the date checks to use `DATEADD` rather than building a string and trying to convert the string to a `DATETIME`

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, looks pretty good however upon trying it I only get null values returned. I wonder if the >< are round the wrong way?

Comment: I've modified my query, try it now.  The datetime conversions from the strings I was building were failing. I suspect that is the reason why you were getting null values.

Comment: Still getting null returned. If I remove the average functions, the IR,SR,CR times add in the workitem ID (to see what the datediff is for each workitem) and not getting anything back either. I'll have a play around with this to see what happens

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the Where DATEPART(WEEKDAY,wi.CreatedDate) NOT IN (1,7) 
            AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,IR.FirstAssignedDate) NOT IN (1,7)
            AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,SR.FirstAssignedDate) NOT IN (1,7)
            AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CR.FirstAssignedDate) NOT IN (1,7)
            AND(

Comment: Hmm... I think the Resolved, Completed, and ActualEnd dates probably need to move to the WHERE in the outer query.  I thought of another issue though... if the CreatedDate and the FirstAssignedDate span multiple days this will still include nonworking hours in the average... I'll work on a revision.

Comment: Actually, it would probably be more efficient to move the DATEPARTs to  a WHERE clause in the outer-most query

Comment: Thanks for the step in the right direction, I believe I've now got something that works

Comment: The only issue I see with your solution is that I think it will include non working hours if the dates span multiple days during the work week.  i.e. Created on Monday, Assigned on Wednesday. I'll point out that my attempted solution has that issue as well.

Comment: It did include the non-working hours as well. I've not put a piece of extra code in to remove the non-working hours.